# Select Id+1 from subquery on same table

Tags: sql, subquery, querying

I need to select all `id + 1` and `id - 1` row information from `MYTABLE` with condition that `id` exist in existing query on same table .

I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE
    id - 1 IN (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE EXISTINGQUERY) AND
    id + 1 IN (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE EXISTINGQUERY)
```

But it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would all really help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you may write your query by using join like below

```
SELECT t1.* FROM MYTABLE t1 
join (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE EXISTINGQUERY) t2 
on (t1.id-1=t2.id or t1.id+1=t2.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following *SELECT statement* may be used that includes the substitution variable `:id`

```
SELECT s.* 
  FROM MYTABLE s 
 WHERE id in (:id - 1,:id + 1) 
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM MYTABLE s WHERE id =:id AND EXISTINGQUERY);
```

where colon(`:`) notation may be replaced with `@` or `&` depending on the database.